# "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError Entity '<class ''>' has no property ... " exception after updating database

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update row in SQLite table by id.

I have class

```
class newTestCaseData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_cases'
    __table_args__ = {"useexisting": True}


    failure_datails = Column('failure_details', String)
    exec_status = Column('exec_status', String)
    execution_duration = Column('execution_duration', String)

    def __init__(self, failure_details=None, execution_duration=None, exec_status = None):
        self.failure_datails = failure_details
        self.execution_duration = execution_duration
        self.exec_status = exec_status
```

And here is my method for updating row in the table:

```
def update_by_external_id(self, tc_external_id, add_tc_status, add_tc_duration, add_failure_details):
    self.new_session.query(newTestCaseData).filter_by(external_id=tc_external_id).\
            update({
                    'exec_status': add_tc_status,
                    'execution_duration': add_tc_duration,
                    'failure_details': add_failure_details})
        self.new_session.commit()
```

After this execution I get error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'models.TestCaseData.newTestCaseData'>' has no property 'failure_details'`

But everything works fine if I delete 'failure_details' from method 'update_by_external_id':

```
def update_by_external_id(self, tc_external_id, add_tc_status, add_tc_duration):
    self.new_session.query(TestCaseDatas).filter_by(external_id=tc_external_id).\
            update({
                    'exec_status': add_tc_status,
                    'execution_duration': add_tc_duration})
        self.new_session.commit()
```

Here is 'failure_details' column in SQLite Studio:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your class has name `newTestCaseData` but you make query using different name `query(TestCaseDatas)`. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: It was the mistake when I copy-paste text from IDE. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There is spelling mistake in the "failure_datails"